# Merkle Hellman Knapsack cryptosystem

Tags: encryption

I am working on a java problem that implements Merkle Hellman's Knapsack. The wikipedia page is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Hellman_knapsack_cryptosystem.

After testing with some simple sample data, some of them are successful while others are not. For example,
input = 'f'; (01100110)

Encryption:

```
w = ( 1,2,4,7,12,20,33,54)

r = 147 

q = 250

b = (147,44,88,29,14,190,101,188)

r-1(reverse) = 233    (r*r-1 mod q =1)

The cryptogram is therefore 423 (=44+88+190+101)

Decryption:

Then 423 * 233 mod 250 = 59

59-54=5
5-4=1
1-1=0
```

THE RESULT is 10100001. But it is WRONG!

I have checked it numerous times and just cannot find which step is wrong with my process. Also, I am aware that the numbers I use should be random. Here, I just want to give an example.

Could anyone shed some lights on this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your w is not superincreasing.

Answer (score 0):

There are conditions for Merkle-Hellman you should follow in order for your output to be correct, here are they:

1. the simple knapsack must be super-increasing
2. the weight(multiplier) must be greater in value than the sum of your simple knapsack
3. the modulus and weight values mustn't have a common factor